# C++ Encoding (special character Ø,é...)

Tags: c++

I work with
C++/Windows/minGw

I get from file .xml a string with special character
The rise witting on the file xml is "Quimby_éé_ØØ R90 GP_NomPoints.txt"
The result is different with strangs characters

My file.xml sounds ok :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Test :

When I get from file .txt a string with special character ,it dosesn't work
When I write the string to .txt file it works fine.

Then There might be some problem with the ide console.

My code:

```
void parser_fichier_xml(string fich,string &ActPoints,string &NomPoints)
{

//string ActPoints;
//string NomPoints;

TiXmlDocument doc(fich.c_str());

if(doc.LoadFile(TIXML_ENCODING_UTF8))
{
TiXmlHandle hdl(&doc);                                          
TiXmlElement *elem = hdl.FirstChildElement("GeometryData").FirstChildElement("Element").Element();   //Création de elem (arbre DOM constituant noeud --enfant)


if(!elem)
{
cout<<"le noeud à atteindre n'existe pas"<<endl;
//return 1;
}                                                     //boucle pour vérifier que l'élément ait bien un enfant

 /* ********* Recuperer chemin nompoint actpoint dans balise XML *********** */


 ActPoints = elem->Attribute("ActPoints");
 NomPoints = elem->Attribute("NomPoints");

 /* *****test dans fichier de sorti ***** */

string const nomFichier("Z:/Production/Methodes/InfoTec/Developpement/Zeiss_PCM/toCALYPSO/test.txt");
ofstream fichier(nomFichier.c_str());

    if(fichier)
    {
        fichier << NomPoints<< endl;


            fichier.close();
    }
    else
            cerr << "Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier test.txt !" << endl;

        /* ************************************************** */


    debug_string("Chemin ActPoints:  ",ActPoints,"Chemin   NomPoints:  ",NomPoints); //affiche dans console

 }
else
{
cerr << "Erreur d'ouverture du fichier .XML" << endl;
}


}
```

As answers, I doesn't like a function that replace special character but something that changes all

If someone may help me

Thks a lot

Comment: Do you know what UTF-8 is? Also, please provide us with a minimal code example - no commented-out old code, no french comments pls.

Comment: You send to the console some special chars "à".  Are these displayed as you expect on the console ?

Answer (score 0):

The windows console barely supports Unicode, definitely not UTF-8, and MinGW's `std::cout` doesn't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Thks for answers,

For comments.i will minimise my vode the next time.

I know what UFT-8 is ,
ASCII isn't enough (without Ø ,é ...)
UNICODE is theoric

For pratical , i've 2 choices ISO 8859 or UTF-8 and
UTF-8 is more complete (japanese ,etc..)

Test :

I tried this special chars " à " and the result is " á "

The display(cout or printf) is not important because i get the value(the result) like path.

i'm going to try with ISO 8859 but even with a file text that contains "éé_ØØ " , the console doesn't write same "éé_ØØ "

Sorry i can't send the picture of the result (this website ask 10 reputations)